# Sharepoint, error on adding a webpart to a totally new page

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint

I have a problem on adding a webpart to sharepoint page.

I have a blank page in the sharepoint, and I have a custom control uploaded to the site, on adding the webpart the the sharepoint page I get the following error:

"Attempted to use an object that has ceased to exist. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80030102 (STG_E_REVERTED))"

I get that error even if the sharepoint page is totally blank and so is the web part.

Comment: Is this any use for you? http://markanthonyparker.blogspot.com/2010/07/attempted-to-use-object-that-has-ceased.html mat-dot-net is on the right track I feel.

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to the server file system, look at "ULS trace"  files found at `c:\program files\common files\microsoft shared\web server extensions\12\logs`. There is a lot of information - much more than you need. Search for the name of your ascx file.

Answer (score 1):

you might have a using() statement on an object that you are not instantiating